# how to load last visited web history in Chrome extension development?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome extension. but when I add this so that get the last visited website ,

```
 chrome.history.search({ 'text': '', 'startTime': closedTime, 'maxResults': 1 },
    function (historyItems) {
        //do stuff
    }
    );
```

It causes this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'search' of undefined

My spell is right，but I don't know what happen? what can i do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Before using the API, you must request the permission to use it via the manifest file:

```
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "history"
  ],
  ...
}
```

(This is also mentioned in [the documentation for `chrome.history`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#manifest)).